# Proof that not every computable function over the natural numbers can be described using structural recursion.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, recursion

I'm reading Bird's Algebra of programming (excelent book so far). It says

> It is a fact that not every computable function over the natural numbers can be
>   described using structural recursion

I think the most reasonable way to do that is assume the negation, that is, "every computable function over the natural numbers can be described using structural recursion" and then find a counter-example.

The counter-example I though was the $sqrt$ function. But from here I'm stuck.

Can anyone tell me how to continue from here or other ways of prove it (assuming other ways exist)?

Comment: It might be helpful to know exactly how Bird defines structural recursion over the integers, that is, what is and is not allowed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Square root isn't a function over natural numbers, unfortunately, since $\sqrt{2}$ isn't a natural...

You can prove the claim non-constructively by diagonalizing: there are uncountably many functions over the naturals, but only countably many can be built up using structural recursion.

For a constructive example, there are functions that grow "too fast" to be captured by structural recursion; the most famous of these is the [Ackermann function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_function).